# What's the difference between [NSMutableString string] and ""

Tags: objective-c, xcode

After self.currentProperty = [NSMutableString string] I saw invalid expression on that thing on the bottom thingy in xcode 4 window (what do you call that? The one showing all watch variables, and expressions, etc.)

How do I initialize self.currentProperty, which is an NSMutableString object to an empty string?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with [NSMutableString string] by itself. What is the error you are seeing? Grab a screenshot if you can't describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
self.currentProperty = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
```

but

```
self.currentProperty = [NSMutableString string];
```

should also be ok.

Can you show us how your property is declared?

Comment: Do they mean exactly the same thing? namely with setting the self.currentProperty into the empty string>?

Comment: @Jim Thio I don't know how both class methods have been implemented, but both return an instance which is autoreleased, to claim ownership you use the dot syntax to use the synthesized setter, assuming that the property is declared as `@property (retatin) ...;`;